# how to compare a different data types in conditional operator for pig latin script....?

Tags: apache-pig

our requirement is to match a char array data type with integer data types in conditional operator or case statement this matches o/p also in integer data types, and i tried to matched both data types and get answered in integer.

```
A = LOAD 'DATA' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int,Name:char array);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (A.Name is NULL ? 'NO NAME' : A.Name);
dump B;
```

I'm getting this ERROR 1050:  Unsupported input type for BinCond

Comment: No matter how hard I try, I cannot understand a word. Could you explain it a little bit better?

Comment: To set a integer data type as conditional and get a output as char array data type

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
A = LOAD 'DATA' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int, name:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE id as id, (name is null ? 'no name' : name) as name;
dump B;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use casting for this. Please go through the following guideline 
**http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#cast**

A = LOAD 'DATA' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int,Name:char array);
dump A;
(,tetst32m)

B=FOREACH A GENERATE ((chararray) A.id is NULL ? 'CHECK' : A.id);
dump B;
(CHECK)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: can you explain the script.why we dump A and B both here then (,tetst32m),(CHECK) why we used this here?

Comment: Well. I was just explaining it. Dump is for temporary output. so, please ignore that.